# Why I am having an error on send_keys using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, autologin

I'm trying to make a script that logs me into my account automatically and I'm stuck at `send_keys`.

I have the latest version of `selenium`, I'm using python `2.7.18`.

here is my script:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

username = 'username'

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

sleep(4)

email = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input'
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(email).send_keys(username)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Jameel\Desktop\selenium1.py", line 14, in <module>
    login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(email).send_keys(username)   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result
missing 'value'   (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)   (Driver info:
chromedriver=2.31.488763
(092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT
10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

I know the script isn't complete.

Comment: code works correctly for me on Python 3.7, Linux Mint,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally different sites follow different design approaches, which doesn't allow normal script flow & needs additional steps to be added.

In you case, the default CSS style blocks your input. So, first click on that element( Which makes it as focused) then send your keys.

Element Attribute differences below,

[Before click action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOVm4.png)

[After click action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tigB8.png)